# MySQL: Unable to calculate percentage properly

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema an data, I want to calculate percentage of the column `code_frequency'.

[image]

I tried the following query but it is giving percentage `1.00` which is definitely wrong. What wrong am I doing here?

```
select code_frequency/sum(code_frequency) as percent,code_frequency
from image_colors where image_id =1
group by code_frequency
```

[image]

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? Do `Select Version();` and report the result.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya `5.7.25`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are grouping on code_frequency and since you have only one row per code_frequency , sum() is going to be same as the code_frequency value itself, and thus getting the ratio as `1`.

Now, in the absence of Windowing functions (you have older version of MySQL), you will have to calculate the Sum separately in a Subquery (Derived Table) and then do a `Cross Join` back to the main table to get the percentages.

```
Select t.code_frequency/dt.sum_freq as percent, t.code_frequency 
From image_colors as t 
Cross Join
( Select SUM(code_frequency) as sum_freq
  From image_colors
  Where image_id = 1
) as dt
Where t.image_id = 1
```